# How to create an STL object of iterators of template Type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, iterator, g++

How to create an STL object of iterators of template Type?
I am trying to create an STL Object (say Vector) of iterators of a template type as below

```
vector<vector<T>::iterator> it1;
```

This fails both in g++ and VC++ where. Both the compilers almost says the same thing

**g++**

```
Main.cpp:8:49: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter li
st for `template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair'
Main.cpp:8:49: error:   expected a type, got `std::vector<T>::iterator'
```

**VC++**

```
error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'std::vector<T>::iterator' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
```

Off-course if you are creating an iterator of Concrete Type it works for example

```
vector<vector<int>::iterator> it1;
```

Here is a minimum failing example

```
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class Spam {
public:
    vector<vector<int>::iterator> it1; #Compiles Fine
    vector<vector<T>::iterator>   it2; #Fails
    };
```

**NOTE**

What I understood from the answers is if a type if dependent then one needs to prefix the keywords `typename`. If that is so then

```
vector< vector<T>  >  it;
```

should also fail but it doesn't. It only seems to fail and require a `typename` keywords iff the dependent name is a `typedef`

Comment: Your NOTE is incorrect. Any dependent name which names a type would require `typename`, but in the `vector<vector<T> >` case there's no dependent name. (Neither `vector` nor `T` is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `typename` as:

```
vector<typename vector<T>::iterator>   it2;
```

It is because `iterator` is a dependent name, as it depends on the template argument `T`.

As a sidenote, be aware that iterators of a vector get invalidated when the vector resizes itself. So a vector of such iterators may not be as useful as you *might* think. To make such a vector useful, make sure that the vector never resizes itself whose iterators you're going to store in this vector of iterators.

Comment: What I understood from the answers is if a type if dependent then one needs to prefix the keywords `typename`. If that is so then

    vector< vector<T>  >  it;

should also fail but it doesn't. It only seems to fail and require a `typename` keywords iff the dependent name is a `typedef`

Comment: @Abhijit:  `vector< vector<T> >` is not a dependent name. Dependent-names are nested names, of the form of `SomeType<T>::SomeName`; here `SomeName` is a dependent name.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the typename keyword:

```
vector<typename vector<T>::iterator>   it2;
```

[This](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) page helped me the most to understand it.

Comment: What I understood from the answers is if a type if dependent then one needs to prefix the keywords `typename`. If that is so then

    vector< vector<T>  >  it;

should also fail but it doesn't. It only seems to fail and require a `typename` keywords iff the dependent name is a `typedef`

Comment: @Abhijit you are halfway there. It not only needs to be dependant but also qualified, which `vector< vector<T> >` is not. I again can only recommend the Link I posted, it is very well explained there.

Comment: @Abhijit `vector< vector< T > >` cannot be anything but a type while `vector< T >::iterator` could conceivably be something else.  In the latter case, you need to inform the compiler that you're expecting a type.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked soon many times...

```
 vector<typename vector<T>::iterator>
```

The problem is that the nested type `iterator` is dependent on the arguments to your template, so you need to tell the compiler that it is a type, or else it will assume that it is a regular template.

Comment: Agree that it's asked far too often. Compilers really should suggest it ("Did you mean `vector<typename vector<T>::iterator>` ?").

Comment: @MSalters GCC 4.6 does it for me